# Solving maze using backtracking in C error

Tags: c, backtracking, maze

Im trying to find the best way to exit a maze ([N][N] array, N<20) where 1's are passages, and 0's are walls.
starting from the top left [0][0], exiting from bottom right[N-1][N-1].

Im getting the following error:
error C2371: 'is_min' : redefinition; different basic types

any idea what I'm doing wrong?
thanks in advance

```
int search_path(int n, int maze[][N], int i,  int j){

    int maxlen = 400;
    int current_best;


    if (maze[i][j] == 0) return False;
    if (maze[i][j] == -1) return False;
    if (i==N-1 && j==N-1 ) return True;

    maze[i][j] = -1;

    if(i < N-1) 
        is_min(n,maze,i,j+1,&maxlen);
    if  (i >0 ) 
        is_min(n,maze,i-1,j,&maxlen) ;
    if  (j < N-1 ) 
        is_min(n,maze,i,j+1,&maxlen) ;
    if  (j >0 ) 
        is_min(n,maze,i,j-1,&maxlen);

     maze[i][j] = 1;

    if ((maxlen == 400)||(maxlen ==0))
        return False;

     return maxlen+1;

};

void is_min(int n, int maze[][N], int i, int j, int *maxlen){

    int current_best = search_path(n,maze, i, j);

    if ((current_best < *maxlen) && (current_best > 0)){
        *maxlen = current_best;};
};





    void path(int n, int maze[][N])
{
    //find best path, starting from 0,0
    int best = search_path(n, maze, 0,0);

    if (best == 0){
        printf("No path found!\n");}
    else
        printf("Shortest path length is:%d\n", best);

 }
```

Comment: Do you have a prototype of `is_min`? Really the message is telling you pretty much everything.

Comment: what does a prototype of is_min mean?

Comment: Ok.. .show the full code then.

Comment: the main calls for path

Comment: Show the full code. *Please*.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/GH7cagqT

Comment: What's in `test_data.h`?

Comment: a few test mazes, together with other test cases for the other Qs



int maze1[N][N] = {
 {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
 {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
 {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1},
 {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1},
 {0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1},
 {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1},
 {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}};

Comment: You need to declare functions before you use them.  If you're compiling with a C compiler that still allows the ancient C90 semantics, rather than the old C99 semantics or the current C11 semantics, then the compiler assumes from your use of `is_min()` that it returns an `int`, and gets upset when you define it and say it returns `void` (nothing) instead.  That's what the error message means.  At minimum, declare functions before you use them.  Often, it is better to define the function before you use it — reverse the order of the functions.

Comment: So no prototype I guess. Prototype is that declaration @JonathanLeffler is talking about.

Comment: Thank you @JonathanLeffler and EugeneSh , indeed after switching the functions the program compiled.
but now I have a new issue that it doesn't find the best path

Comment: Also, you should not place empty variable definitions after functions.  You have `void is_min(int n, int maze[][N], int i, int j, int *maxlen){ … };` and that trailing semicolon is not needed.  Some compilers will warn about it.  Technically, that semicolon marks the end of a variable definition — but a variable definition with neither type nor variable name, hence 'empty'.

Comment: Fixing your algorithm is a separate problem.  Go resolve it using your debugger to see where it is going wrong, or use debugging print statements.  Fixing the code when running is not a part of the initial problem.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, Thank you very much